# Grails eager dynamic finder

Tags: grails, grails-orm

If I load a list of domain classes using a dynamic finder, e.g.

```
List<Book> books = Book.findAllByPublicationYear(2013)
```

My understanding is that the list of books will be lazily loaded, such that if I then iterate over them

```
books.each { println "$it.title" }
```

I will execute N + 1 queries. Is there a way to make the dynamic finder eagerly load the list of books (without rewriting the query using HQL or criteria)?

Comment: Witch version of Grails? I enabled sql output and it generated only one query for me.

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.1.5

Comment: In the DataSource.groovy you add `logSql=true` in the datasource block and `format_sql = true` in the hibernate block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic Finder is always eager fetch for (non-associated) members of the domain. For example, if `publicationYear` being a part of `Book` you will always run one query to get all the books matching the `plublicationYear`. My query looks like

```
select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.version as version0_0_, 
this_.name as name0_0_,this_.publication_year as publicat4_0_0_ 
from book this_ 
where this_.publication_year=?
```

In case you have an association in `Book` say (`Author`) you can programmatically say in the domain class whether you want to `fetch` the association `eagerly` or `lazily` by using this mapping:(default is lazy)

```
static mapping = {
        author lazy: false //or authors if you have multiple authors for a Book
    }
```

or

`static fetchMode = [author: 'eager']`